# set Null to value when use Is null in where

Tags: sql, select

I get this table :

[image]

I use this where :

```
where FoodID=1
```

when i Change My where with this :

```
where FoodID=1 and DayId=1 or DayId is null
```

Filed dayid value change to null for All rows .

[image]

**Note :**

> My where Statement generate with Special Framework : I write this Code
>   in framework :

```
@@wheresql or dayid is null
```

I don't know why change value to null when use is null in where ?

Comment: check my solution  where FoodID=1 and (DayId=1 or DayId is null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `()` arround the or operator:

```
where FoodID=1 and (DayId=1 or DayId is null)
```

if not first the `and` operator is evaluated and then `or`

Answer (score 0):

```
 where FoodID=1 and (DayId=1 or DayId is null)
```

Comment: my where satement generate with special framework . I must write :  @ @@wheresql or dayid is null

Comment: then append replace that with and (DayId=1 or DayId is null) Instead of and DayId=1

Answer (score 0):

You must carefully deal with fences and logical operators, because they have priorities (AND have higher priority over OR operator), so it is not same:

```
where FoodID=1 and (DayId=1 or DayId is null)
```

and

```
where (FoodID=1 and DayId=1) or DayId is null
```

If you omit fences in your expression, then your expression take second shape, so you must explicitly define logical order of expression validation, it is:

```
where FoodID=1 and (DayId=1 or DayId is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `ISNULL` like this:

```
where FoodID=1 and ISNULL(DayId,1) = 1
```

This might remove one of your condition in `where` clause.

Comment: ISNULL is a product specific function (no dbms specified). COALESCE is the ANSI SQL version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is operator precedence. The boolean `and` has precedence over `or`, so `FoodID=1 and DayId=1 or DayId is null` is interpreted as `(FoodID=1 and DayId=1) or DayId is null`. Since your table does not have any rows with `FoodID=1 and DayId=1`, only rows with `DayId is null` are returned.

If you want to query rows with `FoodID=1` and a `DayId` which is either `1` or `null`, you need to explicitly use brackets: `FoodID=1 and (DayId=1 or DayId is null)`